# Keyboard layout changed

Tags: macos

For no apparent reason my Mac mini keyboard has just changed its placement of symbols: For example, whenever I type Shift+2, expecting the @ symbol to appear, I get a " character instead. Language has always been set to British. Nothing to my knowledge has been changed. I am using OSX Yosemite version 10.10.5. How do I get my keyboard back to how it was please?

Comment: System Preferences > Keyboard > Input sources > check *Show input menu in the bar*. What is the flag country that appears on the top bar?

Comment: Britsh and underneath British PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to system preferences/keyboard/input sources and remove the item called "British PC" and make sure only the item called "British" is there.